# PHP Добавить элемент в начало ассоциативного массива

Tags: php, массивы

есть массив

```
Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange Object
(
    [collection_key:protected] => values
    [majorDimension] => ROWS
    [range] => 'Аркуш1'!A1:Z1000
    [values] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => карта напечатана и ожидает отгрузки заводом
                )
```

.....

задача: добавить еще 1 элемент в раздел values чтоб

```
[2] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                        [1] => 
                        [2] => карта напечатана и ожидает отгрузки заводом
                    )
```

имел значение 3, ну и все остальные поменяли свое значение на +1

array_unshift($response, " ");

не помогло

```
$arr= array();
$arr['values']['0']['0'] = "1";

$response2 = $arr + $response;
```

тоже толку не дало, выдает порожний елемент

**UP: Решение нашел, сделал вот так**

```
$l=1;
$resp[0]=array(
        array(
        "0"=>"0"
        )
    );


for ($z = 0; $z <count($response['values']); $z++) {

    $resp[$l]=$response['values'][$z];
    $l=$l+1;
}
```

Comment: Так я понимаю что `$response` это первый массив. ТАк это вовсе не массив а объект, к нему вы обращаетесь `$response->values[0][0]` - собсна также и добавляем.

Comment: Посмотрите на PHP не как на средство разработки говносайтов типа 1сБитрикс, а как современный язык программирования на котором написаны такие монстры как Symfony или Laravel, Yii в конце концов.

Рассмотрите свою задачу на предмет использования вместо массива - объекта. Создаете класс, создаете нужные вам методы для манипуляции с данными. Если вам в итоге нужен именно массив куда то отдать - попросту нормализуете объект. Благо для этого достаточно библиотек написано.
Все эти адовы конструкции что вы приводите как решение вопроса - попросту не читаемы. Через две недели вы не поймете что тут.

Comment: `$l = $l + 1;` можно заменить на `$l =+ 1;`, или `$l++;`